# Power BI create a measure grouping Max(Date) that selects only MaxDate Row

Tags: powerbi

First, new  to Power bi.  I can do this  with tsql as directquery, but want to see  how it is  done with power bi using import.
I have  the  following  table  structure
one  to  many device to metric
device
id, devicename, column3....

metric
id, Device_ID, metric1,  metric2,  createddate.

| DeviceName | metric1 | Metric2 | createdDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| netsclprdelr09 | 44.70 | 14.73 | 2021-11-15 20:00:01.343 |
| netsclrprdctc13 | 8.90 | 6.66 | 2021-11-15 20:00:01.343 |
| netsclrprdelr16 | 7.40 | 6.58 | 2021-11-15 20:00:01.343 |
| netsclprdelr09 | 40.50 | 14.95 | 2021-11-15 19:00:01.567 |
| netsclrprdctc13 | 9.20 | 6.64 | 2021-11-15 19:00:01.567 |
| netsclrprdelr16 | 8.00 | 6.59 | 2021-11-15 19:00:01.567 |
| netsclprdelr09 | 44.70 | 14.93 | 2021-11-15 18:00:01.120 |
| netsclrprdctc13 | 9.20 | 6.66 | 2021-11-15 18:00:01.120 |
| netsclrprdelr16 | 9.00 | 6.62 | 2021-11-15 18:00:01.120 |

I   am  only  looking to return the  first  3  rows (max(Createddate). eliminating  all  other.
I  would suspect  this could be  done with  the  calculate function and some  filters,  but  I  am stuck. Thanks

Comment: Use TOPN function